# Level 30's Files Re-organization

Tags: 2011, cme

I am trying to re-organized level 30's files and folders. What is the easiest way to shuffle files and folders around without having to duplicate any components, files and or image folders? There are content placing all over the the 30 level and I need to consolidate to make it easier for Admin.

[image]

Comment: Note there's nothing special about "030" aside from it being a naming convention to order Publications that also hints this is high in a given BluePrint. The answers below apply as long as the components are *local* to the Publication (i.e. parent) versions. The "from Publication" column should be blank, otherwise you can't move items.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in other answers, as long as you are not trying to move items between Publications, using `Cut` and `Paste` will maintain the relationships between referenced items.

[image]

[image]

In addition to those listed within other answers. there are two more things that you'll need to consider:

### 1. Mandatory Schemas on Folders

If the Folder that you are trying to Paste in to has a mandatory Schema set (i.e. All Components within that Folder must use the Schema specified)...

[image]

...Then you cannot `Cut` and `Paste` a Component using a different Schema in to it. If you try this, then you will get the following error:

[image]

### 2. Unique Item Names

You cannot have two Folders/Components with the same name within the same Folder. If you attempt to `Cut` and `Paste` a Component/Folder in to a Folder that already contains an item with that name, then you'll get a error message.

[image]

**Additional hints:**

1. You may want to take this opportunity to tidy up your Component & Folder names, and ensure that any naming convention that you use is enforced throughout.
2. You will probably want to do this re-organisation in the Production environment, as Content Porter uses WebDav paths (i.e. the names and locations of items within Tridion) and will create lots of duplicate items.
3. If you do make these changes in Production, then you'll want to refresh your other (non-Production) environments as soon as possible.
4. There is often caching in the navigation tree structure. You may need to `Refresh` this frequently during your re-organisation to prevent confusion.

Comment: @stran, screenshots in answer is from Tridion 2013, so don't get confused, but the process is same

Comment: Yes, Raj is correct. The screenshots are from SDL Tridion 2013 GA. Please let me know if you need the equivalents from 2011.

Comment: I would also point out Cut & Paste works with search as well as multiple items (`SHIFT` and `CTRL`) for "batch" Cut & Paste (i.e. *moves*). Regarding #2, this applies to BluePrinting as well, so parent and child items can't have conflicts (Tridion will explain errors though). In terms of dependencies, sometimes a setup might use folders paths for binary publish locations and Ant P has some good points on such dependencies in [this answer](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/5585/46). Oh and you'll have to share your "screen clip and draw" tool, Jonathan. ;-)

Comment: Some excellent points there - thanks Alvin. My screenshots are just taken with CMD + CTRL + SHIFT + 4 (on the Mac) and then Paintbrush. I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do it - still trying to figure out this new Planet Mac with all it's moons!

Comment: @stran If one of the answers here resolved your question, can you please 'Accept' it. If not, please let us know what additional information you would like.

Answer (score 3):

Its cut and paste task as you don't want to duplicate it.(as mentioned by experts above). but few points i want to add if your are performing this activity in same publication.

- it could be slow process and timeout also when you have lot's of stuff in a folder, so  take batches of small items.
- Webdav URL of those items would break(if used anywhere)
- You may have to revisit your security settings, if using  "Inherit Security Settings from Parent" on folders

Comment: +1. WebDAV Urls might show up in template code or "configuration" components and are used by Content Porter as Jonathan mentions.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 030 level is one Publication you should be able to copy/cut and paste the items. Copy/cut and paste will keep all component linking in place, so should be pretty painless.

n.b. If you copy a parent component e.g.

`Component A`, with Component Links `1`, `2` & `3`

and rename it to be `Component B`, the it will still link to Component Links `1`, `2` & `3`. These will need to be updated separately if required.

In your case, take for example a Component `A` with several Multimedia Components in it. Within the same publication you could move the Component `A` and/or any or all of the images without breaking the links between them. Simply copy/cut and paste to a preferred location.

Copy/Cut and paste can be used on all items (Components, Folders and Pages etc..) as long as it is within the same publication.

If you are looking to move items across publications, as Nick says, you will need to recreate them. Depending how many items you are looking to move you can either do this manually, or create a Core Service script to move them programatically. Careful consideration should be made to maintain cross-linking and pages with either approach.

Another approach I have used in the past, but really depends on circumstances is to use Content Porter to move items across publications. In effect tricking Content Porter to move the items across publication using re-naming. Again, this should be done with caution and considering all implications.

These few blog posts and other SE question cover the approaches at a high level

[Using Core service to copy items to different publications](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/824/using-core-service-to-copy-items-to-different-publications)

http://davideguida.altervista.org/sdl-tridion-move-items-across-publications/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to actual (Cut & Paste) moves, `Favorites`, saved Searches (`Virtual Folders`), and `Bundles` (only for Tridion 2013) can help content authors and administrators find components and pages.

I would also consider double checking what "easier" means, I've found customers apply different folder structures depending on the use case. For example you might have:

- An **initial setup** or page creation where folders match pages, focusing on creating "types" of pages
- Folders for **production and maintenance**, where finding items by type, date, channel, or team might be more important

See my [post on the differences](http://www.createandbreak.net/2014/06/fields-and-folders-are-about-how-not.html).

In the long run, where to *find* items might be more useful to authors than where to *put* them. With this in mind, I'd have your "admins" confirm their preferences and maybe use Advanced Search to find and then move items by schema, date, author, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Tridion has a very useful Cut and Paste feature. You can simply use the Cut option in the item's context menu, or using the buttons in the tool bar, and in a similar manner, paste it in the new location. You can select multiple items and cut and paste them simultaneously.

Another very useful Tridion feature when tidying up is Delete. This can also be found on an item's context menu and in the toolbar. Using the Delete feature will ensure that the item no longer exists to clutter up your system.

For a really successful reorganisation, you may also wish to rename some items. Simply open them up and change the Title.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the forum and the world of Tridion.  If you have the right level of access rights then you will be able to simply cut-paste the folders (and all items within) into other folders.  You can do the same with Components, pages and SGs.

You must note though, that you cannot move items across Publications.  For instance, if you created a Component at the 050 level, then realized it should've been created in 030, you will have to re-create the Component in the correct Publication.  Not only that, you'll also have to relink all the dependencies (e.g. If you have component links and using the component in some way).